# Cordova SSL Error with Certificate Transparency in iOS 10.3

Tags: ios, cordova, security, ionic3, ssl-certificate

After enabling certificate transparency in Ionic application config file, AJAX calls started failing for iOS 10.3 with SSL error. However, it is working without any issues in iOS 11 and greater. Connection with server works fine with native iOS application, Angular Web Application. It fails only in Cordova compiled application.

Configuration which results in failed AJAX communication

```
<access minimum-tls-version="TLSv1.2" origin="https://example.com" requires-certificate-transparency="true" requires-forward-secrecy="false" />
```

Communication works with following setting in XCode

```
<key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>example.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

In network logs, it seems application is sending UNKNOWN during SSL handshake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** - had to revisit the question and read it properly

At first I thought the configuration could be at fault but then the:

> UNKNOWN during SSL handshake

caught my eye.

As of iOS 10.3, the default for new custom certificates is to not
trust them.  Yes, this option existed prior to 10.3 but it was not enforced so it was turn on by default.  You can find this information on a [charles proxy](https://www.neglectedpotential.com/2017/04/trusting-custom-root-certificates-on-ios-10-3/) blog - which is connected to the application, but I think it is valid in your case too.

### To enable the certificate:

You have to go to `Settings > General > About > Certificate Trust Settings` and enable the certificate that is needed.

You can find it mentioned here [Technical Q&A QA1948
HTTPS and Test Servers](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1948/_index.html).

### In addition:

You can use `nscurl` tool to diagnose your ATS connection issues.

Usage `/usr/bin/nscurl --ats-diagnostics [--verbose] URL` then you will what fails in greater detail.